# Our Linux box is running two instanced of mysql?

Tags: linux, mysql

Ok, so I'm not sure what changed as I am by no means an expert in the ways of mysql or linux (I know most of the basics) but when I restart mysql via "service mysqld restart" it doesn't actually restart mysql at all.  Nor will it stop.

So I ran "ps aux | grep mysqld" and noticed its being run by root as well as mysql user?!  Im not really sure how this can happen?

```
root     31191  0.0  0.0  65948  1356 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql

mysql    31896  1.4 23.2 3983432 3823924 ?     SLl  Mar12  56:49 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/db.local.err --open-files-limit=8192 --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Would anyone be able to give some insight on how this could happen?  I did some googling and I dont know if I am using wrong search terms but I'm not finding anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your system.In fact, using `mysqld_safe` is the recommended way of starting mysql in Unix. Check official [documentation here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html)

`mysqld_safe is the recommended way to start a mysqld server on Unix. mysqld_safe adds   some safety features such as restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log file.`

You can tell from the process id that mysqld_safe initiated mysqld, having it run under the user mysql, `--user=mysql`. And all the other run time parameters are specified when starting mysqld_safe, to be used by the mysql daemon.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thats cool but how would I restart the service then?

Comment: use `mysqladmin`. If your mysql root access requires a password, for instance, use `mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown`. Then start it using the `mysqld_safe` command you used to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqld_save` is just a script which in turn calls `mysqld` and does some [additional neat stuff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//mysqld-safe.html). So everything looks fine with your system.